# Mysql json column output backslash

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

It is my first time to use Mysql json column type
when I make post request via Laravel api to make new user
like this

```
"username:andy21, password:123456, profile:{"home_town":"germany"}"
```

I save profile in the Json column
when I retrieve it, it have backslash before every " on the json object
like this

```
"profile":"{\"home_town\":\"germany\"}"
```

my return in laravel controller looks like this

```
return response()->json(['profile'=>$user]);
```

why it have these backslashes and how to remove it ?

Comment: How about the value on the database? Is it backslashed?

Comment: Same as I have sent it, I think it maybe because of the json respons in laravel

Comment: I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if your `$user` variable is in JSON format:

```
return response()->json(['profile' => json_decode($user)]);
```